# error on trying to build gradle - androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.+

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to build a react-native app but it's returning this error:

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.+.
     Versions that do not match:
       - 1.1.0-rc01
       - 1.1.0-beta01
       - 1.1.0-alpha05
       - 1.1.0-alpha04
       - 1.1.0-alpha03
       - + 10 more
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find any version that matches androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:28.+.
     Versions that do not match:
       - 1.1.0-beta01
       - 1.1.0-alpha01
       - 1.0.0
       - 1.0.0-rc02
       - 1.0.0-rc01
       - + 3 more
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-camera
   > Could not find any version that matches androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:28.+.
     Versions that do not match:
       - 1.0.0
       - 1.0.0-rc02
       - 1.0.0-rc01
       - 1.0.0-beta01
       - 1.0.0-alpha3
       - + 1 more
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-firebase
```

My `build.gradle` file is:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        playServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

            defaultConfig {
                targetSdkVersion 27
            }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.0"
}
```

And here is my app level `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 40
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'mlkit'
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    implementation project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-app-settings')
    implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }

     // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6"

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also, my Android Studio has the following components downloaded:

- API 27
- API 28
- Android SDK Build Tools 29
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform Tools
- Android SDK Tools
- Support Repository

I'm totally newbie in java/android, so have no idea on how to deal on that.

Someone can help?

Comment: Please post your app-level `build.gradle` file with the dependencies. As the log says, there should be some wrong versioning on the library dependencies listed in that file.

Comment: @ahmedaljubair updated with information you asked for

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've used AndroidX components without adding its dependencies. Either disable AndroidX support & remove AndroidX components from your XML files with older Android Support components or add the following dependencies to your existing app-level `build.gradle` file :

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0"
}
```

If using AndroidX, recheck if you have these two lines in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Setting these two gradle plugin flags to true means that Android Plugin will use appropriate AndroidX library instead of support Library & will rewrite their binaries. For knowing more how to migrate an entire project to AndroidX, please follow this link:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: is it safe to migrate to androidx? this app has been created by another company and I'm scared about making big changes and cause app problems.

Comment: @anderlaini yes it's safe and you'll get all the prior libraries & their androidx version respectively in the aforementioned link that I provided you with. But if you still don't want to use, just remove the androidx components from xml layout files & that'll resolve the dependency errors. Let me know if I can help with anything else or any error that you're stuck with. And accept the answer too if it helps in either way.